# Inconveniente inserción de registros de Excel VBA a base de datos Mysql PhpMyadmin

Tags: excel, vba

Hola necesito pedirles el favor con lo siguiente:
Necesito insertar registros de una hoja de Excel con el lenguaje VBA a una base de datos que tengo en MySQL (Phpadmin).
Tengo una función de conexión, que es la siguiente:

```
Global con As ADODB.Connection
Global rs As ADODB.Recordset

Sub conexion()
Dim BD$, Servidor$, User$, Clave$
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Let Servidor = "db4free.net": Let BD = "alumnotas"   ' 127.0.0.1
Let User = "usuario de mi BD": Let Clave = "clave de mi BD"  
con.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};" _
     & "SERVER=" & Servidor & ";DATABASE=" & BD & ";" _
    & "UID=" & User & ";PWD=" & Clave & ";PORT=3306"    '   & "UID=" & User & ";PWD=" & Clave & ";PORT=3306;OPTION=131072"
con.Open
End Sub
```

Y tengo un botón asociado a una función de inserción de registros con nombre insertaralumno(), cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
Sub insertaralumno()
   Call conexion
  If con.State = 1 Then
   Dim com As New command
   Dim registros As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   com.ActiveConnection = con
   For i = 4 To 10    ‘ los registros van de la fila 6 hasta la fila 10 en la columna 15 de la hoja 1 
        registros = 0
        com.CommandText = "insert into alumnos(codalumno,nombreal,apellal,correoalu,passwalu,telefalu,direalu) values ('" & Hoja1.Cells(i, 15) & "' )"  ' 15 es la columna O
        com.CommandType = adCmdText
        com.Execute registros
          If registros > 0 Then
            MsgBox "registro insertado"
            Else
            MsgBox "No se inserto registro"
           End If
   Next i
   con.Close
  Else
       MsgBox "Hay  problema en la conexion"
    
  End If
End Sub
```

Al oprimir el botón me muestra el siguiente error:
“Se ha producido el error ‘-2147468259’ en tiempo de ejecución:
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.31]Column count doesn´t match value count at row 1”

Interpretando dicho error según las ayudas en la web, pareciera ser que no coincide el valor de los For que son 7 que van de la fila 4 hasta la 10, con el numero de campos en la tabla alumnos de la Base de datos (alumnotas) que son 7  (codalumno,nombreal,apellal,correoalu,passwalu,telefalu,direalu)

Vale mencionar que la tabla con nombre alumnos en la base de datos alumnotas, tiene los siguientes campos  (codalumno,nombreal,apellal,correoalu,passwalu,telefalu,direalu) y todos sos de tipo Varchar
Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Según tu código haces un INSERT INTO de varios campos a la vez, pero como VALUES solo pasas `Hoja1.Cells(i, 15)`, que tiene toda la pinta de ser un único valor. Si eliges meter info en varios campos entonces necesitas varios valores. ¿Cuál es el valor de `Hoja1.Cells(i, 15)`?

Comment: Hola Esei, muchas gracias se decidió hacer lo siguiente:  com.CommandText = "insert into alumnos(codalumno,nombreal,apellal,correoalu,passwalu,telefalu,direalu) values ('" & Hoja1.Cells(4, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(5, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(6, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(7, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(8, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(9, 15) & "','" & Hoja1.Cells(10, 15) & "' )"  ' 15 es la columna O
 Gracias!.